# How to show call hierarchy in Ruby in IntelliJ?

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea

Both RubyMine and IntelliJ IDEA documentation say that to show the call hierarchy one should

> On the main menu, choose Navigate | Call Hierarchy.

But when I try in IntelliJ on Ruby code it does not work. The option is simply inactive (gray).

Docs also say that

> You can build and view the hierarchy of callers and callees for a selected method in the Hierarchy tool window. Before viewing call hierarchy, you need to build at least one.

But hierarchy tool does not display call hierarchies, I probably need to do something for it to work. What?

How to I show call hierarchy for a particular method in Ruby in IntelliJ IDEA?

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/2016.1/building-call-hierarchy.html
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/building-call-hierarchy.html
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/hierarchy-tool-window.html

Comment: Yep, inactive for me too. I wouldn't get my hopes up, if I were you. Many of idea's features are near-useless in ruby. Some are __worse__ than useless. For example, try renaming a commonly named method, like `call`. I guarantee you'll have a ton of false positives. cmd+click navigation also often takes me not to my intended location. In such dynamic language as ruby, you just can't have all those nice things.

Comment: Well, I guess that it should work at least partially. Now I'm able to follow graph call by searching each method name separately, would be nice if IDE did that for me. Also they mention it in their RubyMine docs, so I suppose it works there...